# how some part of second activity is visible into first activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a list view in first activity and i want to go to the second activity on click but i want to achieve first view is [like](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evernote&hl=en) this it means some part of second activity is visible into first activity. how can i achieve.

Comment: share a link without the need to login. From the details you provided I can assume that you're thinking either of an activity with transparent (or semi-transparent) background or a `DialogFragment`

Answer (score 0):

In this case, don't create two separate activities. What you can do is, write the xml layout from 2nd activity in 1st activity's xml file, but, keep its visibility as "`GONE`". And on click of button that calls 2nd activity, just make the visibility of this layout as "`VISIBLE`". So you will get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Put the background color of your layout in the second activity to transparent:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```